# How do I get the Sweethearts (Milk+OJ) ribbon?

Tags: bag-it

I am playing Bag It! on Android.

In the first level, you can get a ribbon that is labelled "Sweethearts (Milk and OJ)".

I know if I place Milk beside Orange Juice, they get labelled as sweethearts - do I have to pair up every Milk and OJ in the level? I had one pair, and that was not enough to get the ribbon.

I also had the following layout: (M for Milk, O for OJ, C for cereal)

> MOC
>
> MOC

This got me one "Sweetheart" bonus (for the bottom M/O pair), but no ribbon, and also the "Double Date" bonus (presumably for the stacked Milk and Orange Juices), but still no Sweetheart ribbon.

How do I make sure I get the Sweetheart ribbon at the end of the level?

Comment: 'Double Date' is for two sets of touching 'sweethearts' (Milk + OJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To earn a ribbon, you must qualify for it AND finish the level with at least one star.

Answer (score 2):

The medals are a little unintuitive here - the second ribbon you get (usually unlocked when you score silver) will turn gold when you get it, but the first one will just show up - if it is not a a dotted outline of a ribbon, you have already received it.

Comment: The first one shows up as silver i.e. second prize.  The second medal is generally more difficult to get, and that's why it turns gold.